# How to simulate "set -o vi" in csh , like we do in ksh?

Tags: command, ksh, csh

I used **ksh** a lot but now moving to **csh** as this company has all scripts etc written in that.
One thing I loved about ksh was the ease of using the command history.
In case I have to edit the last command or second last command, I could easily press "**Escape - k**" to cycle through the commands and easily edit them.

csh does not seem to have a good equivalent. It displays all the history of commands then I have to copy paste one of them and then edit.

That's a pain when you want just change the number of in the file name for example :

**cat abcdef1 | grep "Linking"**

Comment: Work-around: I forgot everything about csh, but you can use ksh commands in a new shell (put /bin/ksh in your .cshrc?). This company will migrate to ksh or bash over a few years.

Answer (score 0):

You could use (as a workaround):

*"The most commonly used feature of csh command history is "!!" (pronounced "bang bang") which recalls the previous command":*
% date
Mon Nov 25 13:52:36 PST 1996
% !!
date
Mon Nov 25 13:52:52 PST 1996

[Here](http://tomecat.com/jeffy/tttt/cshhistory.html) some other useful commands.

But you could just work in ksh and make script and whatever in csh.
If it is istalled simply launch:
/bin/ksh